# In Matlab, I want to reuse the ppform given by spline function, how can I do that?

Tags: matlab

I do not want to regenerate a interpolation ppform every time I call a evaluating function, so I really need an efficient implementation that calls spline only once by reusing the ppform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) - the second form of `spline` is what you need:

to get the spline object:

`pp = spline(x,Y)`

and `ppval` or `unmkpp` to reuse it.

**example:**

```
x = pi*[0:.5:2]; 
y = [0  1  0 -1  0  1  0; 
     1  0  1  0 -1  0  1];
pp = spline(x,y);
yy = ppval(pp, linspace(0,2*pi,101));
plot(yy(1,:),yy(2,:),'-b',y(1,2:5),y(2,2:5),'or'), axis equal
```

[image]